# `labels = {'text':''}` in Model.Form

Tags: django

I am little puzzbled about the `labels = {'text':''}` in the following code:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Topic
class TopicForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Topic
        fields = ['text']
        labels = {'text':''}
```

Does `labels = {'text':''}` means

```
<label for='text'> </label>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it means the `label_name` of the field.

```
labels = {'text':'My Name'}
```

The HTML rendered will be something like this:

```
<label> My Name </label>
```

Comment: The tutorial says "tells Django not to generate a label for the text field.", my understanding is if  attribute ` labels` is omitted, it will generate <label> long text </label>, right?

Comment: if attribute ` labels` is omitted, Django will generate it with the `field_name`

Answer (score 1):

As it is described in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/models/#modelform-factory):

> labels is a dictionary of model field names mapped to a label.

So yes, with that you assign `labels` in html.